# How load media by condition in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to load video for desktop only. For this I use a condition with plugin vue-mq.

```
<video
  :src="this.$mq !== 'mobile' ? require('~/assets/video/intro.mp4') : ''"
/>
```

If I look at the tab network in chrome, I see that the video loads for mobile too.

Condition `this.$mq !== 'mobile'` works correctly.

Can someone help me with how to load media separately for different breakpoints in nuxt?

Comment: is 'mobile' a custom breakpoint that you defined?  it's not standard with vue-mq according to the [docs](https://github.com/AlexandreBonaventure/vue-mq) so if you could post how you set up the plugin that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the [Device](https://nuxt.com/modules/device) module? It is available in both Nuxt 2 and Nuxt 3 with some minor difference when installing it.

The Installing process is quite simple and very easy to use. After Installation, you can just use it like

```
<video
  :src="$device.isDesktop ? require('~/assets/video/intro.mp4') : ''"
/>
```

cheers